# How do i write to next Column if Specific Column color changes

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have been trying to find a way or method that whenever Specific Column cell color which is **Purple** changes to another color then write Current date and Time to corresponding column cell.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1j9CzSkvZDcHTDFfCb4LxZ-gT4PLAiKOifi3NsWZJu3U/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: The only way to do it with google apps script is through polling.  You can poll a little faster if you can do it clientside.

Comment: I have tried to find example on Google but all examples are that to change the cell color based on cell value. there is no example which perform above. I would appreciate if you could write something which may help to achieve this.

Comment: Polling just means go read the value that your looking to change and note when it changes.  Surely, you can do this.  If not then I recommend that you start learning how.

Comment: Alright thanks @Cooper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### SUGGESTION:

You can try using the [getBackground()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getbackground) method to get the selected range's current background color & then use an `if` condition if it is in color purple (on your sample sheet, the purple value is `#ead1dc`) or not. Then, you can use an `onChange()` event type [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually) for your script:

***UPDATE:***

Here's a sample implementation:

```
function colorChangeCheck() { 
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  var color = sh.getActiveRange().getBackground();
  var row = sh.getActiveRange().getRow();
  var col = sh.getActiveRange().getColumn();

  if(color == "#ead1dc" || color == "#ffffff"){ //Do nothing if the default color is #ead1dc (Purple) OR #ffffff (White)
    return;
  }else{
    if(sh.getRange(row, col+1).getBackground() == "#ffffff" && sh.getRange(row, col-1).getBackground() == "#ffffff"){ //Disregard if the row being changed is in white color
      return;
    }else{
      sh.getRange("L"+sh.getActiveRange().getRow()).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
    }
  }
}
```

Sample:

> Sheet:

[image]

> Added & saved the sample function `colorChangeCheck` as an `onChange()` installable trigger event type. Guide [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually):

[image]

> ***UPDATE:*** Result after changing one purple row to blue and one white row to blue (the white row that was changed to blue has no timestamp):

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much its working great. But it has to be strict that it should work for just specific color that is `purple` https://imgur.com/fpbE6Ft you can check that when i paste color on default color that is white it also writes the date and time.I inserted the new row and it paste the date and time

Comment: @ShRa I have made some updates to the `if` condition on my answer. You may also want to check [JavaScript if else and else if](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp) to be more familiar with if-else conditions

Comment: Bundle of thanks @Irvin Jay G. You are great.

Comment: I think i could not elaborate well, I just want that whenever Purple color changes to default white color then script should work. It does not work for any other color. except purple to default white @Irvin Jay G.